# sudo kubectl get nodes - The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Following [this documentation](https://upcloud.com/community/tutorials/deploy-kubernetes-using-kubespray/) I was able to setup a master node and three worker nodes. However, when I run the command `sudo kubectl get nodes` after being able to SSH to the master node, I get the following error:

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I also checked `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` for `admin.conf` file if that was causing the error, the file does not exist. In fact, I couldn't find the `/kubernets` directory inside `/etc` directory. Why is there no `kubernetes/admin.conf` folder and file in the first place and how can I solve this issue? Or am I looking at wrong `etc` directory?

Comment: where are you checking for `admin.conf`  ? if your workstation ?? or in the master node ?

Comment: In the workstation. So its supposed to be in the master node?

Comment: Yup...Master node!, you should have a `kubeconfig` file copied to your workstation. It does not happen by default.

Comment: Sir, I passed the `ls` command and there's no `admin.conf` inside of it.

Comment: I do not know much of your environment, but `ls /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` should return the file name in master node. Unless someone removed it.

Comment: I just configured the K8s cluster till that step and there seems to be the entire `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` missing. Does it boil down to how the configuration was done? The entire cluster is hosted on Ubuntu template in UpCloud.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue. Even though the error was with regard to connection refusal, the actual issue was with resource allocation. I noticed that the worker nodes have actually [failed to launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdUh0.png). So I went back and edited the `cluster-settings.tfvars` file and allocated 2046 MiB of memory to each node as it is specified in [Kubernetes official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/memory-constraint-namespace/). Hope this will help anyone who runs into similar issue to mine.